Question about sentence generation according to specific patterns with predefined vocabulary list
I am interested in learning a language and want to generate practice sentences from a predefined vocabulary list according to patterns that I define ie noun(creature) - verb of being - emotion adjective. Chat GPT does a decent job with some of this and I can get it to output what I want some of the time, but is there a better option? Has anyone tried this before?
